# Real-time multiplayer game server development

Tags: android, java, multiplayer, server

I'm an Android developer, and I want to start developing a real-time multiplayer game, like [Pocket Legends](http://pocketlegends.com/).

Would this type of server be good for a real-time multiplayer action game - http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/?

I'm absolutly new to server development, so it would be great if you explaind even more about this stuff ...

Comment: You need a more concurrent server than the one you have linked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm working on my first multiplayer game as well. It can be daunting just learning the problems specific to multiplayer, so I highly recommend that you get good at making single player ones first.

First, see if any of the game/networking engines fit your needs. For an Android game especially, starting with a well-developed toolset is almost always a good idea. Here are some of the popular ones that I know of:

- [Unity](http://unity3d.com/)
- [Marmalade](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/)
- [Raknet](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/)
- [Photon Network Engine](http://www.exitgames.com/)

If you decide to implement the networking code yourself, or if you're curious, you'll need to start learning about the best techniques. After lots of reading myself, I've found these guides to be a cut above the rest:

- [Gaffer on Games: Networking for Game Programmers](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/)
- [Source Multiplayer Networking](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking)
- [Gabriel Gambetta: Fast-Paced Multiplayer](http://www.gabrielgambetta.com/?p=11)

There are many resources available for almost anything you need to learn if you search for them.

Comment: Yeah those 3 articles are great, also [this](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Latency_Compensating_Methods_in_Client/Server_In-game_Protocol_Design_and_Optimization) is great as well.

Answer (score -1):

[ElectroServer](http://www.electrotank.com) is another solution you can use for Flash, Unity, native iOS and Android games. ElectroServer is Java on the server with APIs for AS3, C#, C++, Objective-C, Java, and Javascript. It's used by major companies and indies alike, and supports millions of players every month.

You can find dev resources here: http://www.electrotank.com/resources.html 
The resources include 50 tutorials and examples (text and video), a free 100 CCU trial version, a free forum managed by dedicated senior engineers, and several free game examples.